# ERR (3): Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: product, php, blocks, magento-1, date

What is not correct about this statement? It came from the theme developer's files.

```
ERR (3): Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given  in /home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/local/Peerforest/MultiProduct/Block/Product/Default/Bestseller.php on line 53
```

line 53 - `$currentDate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $currentDate );`

Answer (score -1):

[From the PHP doc, parameter 2 is a timestamp.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

So you need to check what is the value of `$currentDate` before line 53 and how it is set.

If this variable is supposed to be the current timestamp then you can get rid of the second parameter in the code:

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-j');
```

As by default, PHP uses the current timestamp for the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I have applied this change and will test to see if it removes the error